# Angular (2+) - getting a delay in data binding interpolation

Tags: angular, google-maps, data-binding, autocomplete, interpolation

I'm building a location search input using google's location suggestions API. It all works fine, and the results are returned near-instantly, but I'm having several issues with displaying the data.

- The suggestions come back from the service, but can sometimes take several seconds to show in the view (you can see the delay as the results are in the console immediately but take some time to change in the view)
- Sometimes the results shown in the view show the last set of results, not the current results

I've written a basic copy of what I am trying to do on StackBlitz, https://google-location-suggestions.stackblitz.io, and still having the same issues here. I've updated it to have a loading state which better shows the issue.

StackBlitz link with editor:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-location-suggestions

I've also included a video here so you can see what I mean:
https://vimeo.com/271476965

I'd appreciate anyones help if they know why this is happening.

Comment: You maybe forgot to save the stackblitz.

Comment: @ibenjelloun yes I did, thanks - just saved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "delay" is related to change detection, if you click the document after entring a location search, angular will get the event and refresh the DOM.

The maps api is downloaded after the angular loading, which makes the maps code running outside the ngZone. I understood this while reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000577/8945135).

The main fix (as you mentionned previously on your answer) is to use `ngZone.run` to run the code in the Angular Zone :

```
private suggestions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public search(location: string): void {
    this.service.getPlacePredictions(
      {
        input: location,
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'uk' }
      },
      (predictions, status) => this._ngZone.run(() => this.suggestions$.next(predictions.map(p => p.description)))
    );
  }
```

I also added some other improvements :

Loading the maps api only once in the constructor to avoid the already loaded error (also stackblitz aot causes loading the service multiple times, so I change the reload mechanism to page on the left bottom menu) :

```
constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      console.log('Maps API loaded');
      this.mapsApiLoading$.next(false);
    });
  }
```

You could create the desired observable using rxjs pipes :

```
this.locationSuggestions$ = this.locationForm.get('location').valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(location => location && location !== ''),
        switchMap(location =>
            this.appService.getLocationSuggestions(location)));
```

This way you can directly subscribe to your observable in the template using `async` :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="locationSuggestions$ | async as suggestions; else loading">
{{ suggestions | json }}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
  loading...
</ng-template>
```

Sometimes, if I was fast enough I could search before loading the maps api, so I added a loading observable, to let the component know when he could start searching.

[Here is the new stackblitz with the changes.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50490198)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might have something to do with change detection. Unfortunately though your solution seems to do the same thing when I just tried it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the updated edit but the issue still occurs for me in your code? If you type 'na' into the location input it lists 'Nottingham' as the first result whereas it should be 'Natual History Museum...', if you click off the input as you suggested it updates.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize, I was totally wrong about this ^_^)". The main reason of getting outside the ngZone here is the maps api, which means there is no choice but using some of those functions to run code inside the ngZone or run the change detection. This post helped me understand : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000577/8945135. I'm fixed my stackblitz with your solution, and I'm fixing my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read of that. Also going to mark your answer as correct as you include the ngZone in the service which is the best place for it, rather than the component.

Answer (score 1):

Problem as suggested by @ibenjelloun (thank you) was change detection.

I implemented Angular's NgZone to run change detection so that the binding updates by wrapping the code in the `ngZone.run` method

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.locationSuggestionsLoading = false;
    this.locationSuggestions = locations;
});
```

Comment: Using `ngZone.run()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` is not the best way of handling this kind of issues, it makes code complexe. Usually, when I need to use one of those, I just get back and think how I can improve my components/services design to make it work without using them. I made an edit to my answer, with an improved solution.