# Angular 2 interpolation not working inside listener of google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I have an Angular 2 project using google maps. The map initially appeared. When the map is moved, I'd like to get the center of the map and using geocode to get the address. After I get the address, I'd like to show the address to the info screen.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: '<div #map></div>
        <p>{{info}}</p>'
})
export class MapComponent implement OnInit {
    info = 'initial'
    showInfo = string => {
        console.log(this.string);
        this.info = string;
        console.log(this.string);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm using method `showInfo` to help me debug this problem. in the ngOnInit, I'm initializing the map. Funny things is, if I'm calling the show info directly from the ngOnInit, the text inside `<p>{{info}}</p>` on the browser changing

```
ngOnInit() {
    ... // let say I'm already initialize the map
    this.showInfo('test this'); // WORKING
}
```

but after I put a listener into my map it is stop working

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.map.addListener('center_changed', () => {
         const location = ... // let say I'm already get the location
         this.showInfo(location); // NOT WORKING
    });
}
```

suddenly the angular 2 interpolation cannot work and the text in the browser is not changing, the `console.log()` inside the `showInfo()` says the variable `info` already changing but the text inside `<p>{{info}}</p>` is not changing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000577/5695162

Comment: wow, so basically I just need to inject `ApplicationRef` to the component and then call `tick()` on it to make it update? Thanks a lot, problem solved. Please put the answer and I'll put it as accepted answer